# Derivation of generation of time between two subsequent particle enters into computational domain

Tags: simulations, computational-physics, probability, dirac-delta-distributions

I have problem with understanding derivation of one equation in following problem.

You have 1D computational domain (it is not 1D but because it is symmetrical and we are watching only radial velocity and radial position we can assume that it is 1D), one end is probe which is collecting particles. From the second end you are injecting particles with Maxwell-Boltzmann velocity distribution in single direction:

\begin{equation}
f(v_{x}) = \sqrt{\frac{m}{2 \pi k_{B} T}} \exp\left(-\frac{mv_x^2}{2 k_B T}\right)
\end{equation}

Clearly in the interval ($t, t+\Delta t$) only particles which are from the distance $v_x \cdot t$ to the distance $v_x (t+\Delta t)$ can enter into the domain through the area $S$. If concentration of particles is $n$, then number of particles $N$ which enter the domain in time interval ($t, t+\Delta t$) has to be $nSv_x\Delta t$. But we have to take into account velocity distribution, so the number of such particles should be:

\begin{equation}
n S \Delta t \sqrt{\frac{m}{2 \pi k_B T }} \int_{0}^{\infty}v_x \exp\left(-\frac{mv_x^2}{2 k_B T}\right) dv_x = n S \Delta t \sqrt{\frac{k_B T}{2 \pi m}}
\end{equation}

Now, the probability that particle enters the domain during the time interval ($t, t+\Delta t$] can be expressed by cumulative distribution functions. If one cumulative distribution function $F(t)$ represents the probability that particle enters the domain during the time interval ($0, t$], then difference

\begin{equation}
F(t+\Delta t)-F(t)
\end{equation}

has to represent the probability that particle enters the domain during the time interval ($t, t+\Delta t$].

In order to get distribution function of time between enters of particles, now think of small volume $V'$ which is part of volume $V$. The probability that the particle is not in volume $V'$ is:

\begin{equation}
\left( \frac{V-V'}{V} \right)
\end{equation}

But we are not thinking about one particle but about $N$ particles, so the probability that in volume $V'$ is none of these $N$ particles is:

\begin{equation}
\left( \frac{V - V'}{V} \right)^{N} = \left(1 - \frac{V'}{V} \right)^{N} .
\end{equation}

The inverse probability, that in this volume is at least one particle is:

\begin{equation}
P = 1 - \left(1 - \frac{V'}{V} \right)^{N} .
\end{equation}

For $V' \ll V$ we can aproximate this with Taylor expansion. If we take first two terms:

\begin{equation}
P = 1 - \left(1 - \frac{V'}{V} \right)^{N} \approx  1 - \left(1 - N \frac{V'}{V} \right) = N \frac{V'}{V} = n V' .
\end{equation}

The small volume $V'$ is $S \Delta t \sqrt{\frac{m}{2 \pi k_B T }}$.

Now the thing that I really don't understand. The probability that particle enters during the time interval ($t,t+\Delta t$) should be:

\begin{equation}
\label{WeirdEquation}
\tag{1}
F(t+\Delta t)-F(t) = (1 - F(t)) \cdot n S \Delta t \sqrt{\frac{m}{2 \pi k_B T }}
\end{equation}

Then you divide the equation with $\Delta t$ and take limit $\Delta t \rightarrow 0$

\begin{equation}
\dfrac{dF(t)}{dt} = nS \sqrt{\frac{kT}{2 \pi m}} \cdot (1 - F(t)) .
\end{equation}

Solving this equation you get distribution function for time between two subsequent particle enters into the domain. Then method of inverse fuction can be used to achieve time between two subsequent enters:

\begin{equation}
t_i = - \frac{1}{nS} \sqrt{\frac{2 \pi m}{k T}} \ln (\xi)
\end{equation}

where $\xi$ is uniform distribution (0,1). This way you can generate numbers between one and zero and get time between two particle enters into computational domain.

Now back to \ref{WeirdEquation}. The term on the left side is the probability that particle enters during the time interval ($t,t+\Delta t$). Because there is equal sign the terms on the right side has to be the same. The first term $(1 - F(t))$ is the probability that particle do not enter during the time interval ($0,t$). The second term $n S \Delta t \sqrt{\frac{m}{2 \pi k_B T }}$ is number of particles in $V'$ or probability that particle is in $V'$, I don't know. And I don't know why you have to multiply these and why they should give the correct result.

In my opinion, while the particle is from the distance $v_x \cdot t$ to the distance $v_x (t+\Delta t)$ from the border of the computational domain, than it has to enter during the time interval $(t,t+\Delta t)$ and only from it's presence in the volume $V'$ which is from the distance $v_x \cdot t$ to the distance $v_x (t+\Delta t)$ from the border of the computational domain you can deduce that the particle crosses the border of the computational domain during time interval $(t,t+\Delta t)$.